# divs don't align horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the tab divs horizontally, but It doesn't work and I can't find my fault?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Employees</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/calc/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="tab"><a href="/">Home</a></div>
      <div class="tab"><a href="/employee/new">Add Expenses</a></div>
      <div class="tab"><a href="/employee/new">Tags</a></div>
      <div class="tab"><a href="/employee/new">Overview     </a></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#tab {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#tab` should be `.tab`, according to your HTML

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed up classes and ID's. Modify your css to this:

```
.tabs {
   overflow: hidden;
}
.tab {
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to float your **class** .tab instead of an id. Also, when you float elements you need to clear at one point. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Employees</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/calc/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="tab"><a href="/">Home</a></div>
      <div class="tab"><a href="/employee/new">Add Expenses</a></div>
      <div class="tab"><a href="/employee/new">Tags</a></div>
      <div class="tab"><a href="/employee/new">Overview     </a></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
   clear: both;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hM62P/**

Comment: +1 for fiddle. What's the .clear good for? In your fiddle it looks the same without it.

Comment: You always need to clear floated elements at one point. If you don't in your example .tabs wouldn't wrap around your nested elements anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are using #tabs and #tab, which is not at all available in your HTML. # refers to ID. You need to use .tabs and .tab which refers to a class.

```
.tabs{
     width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.tab{
    float:left;
}
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/B35ED/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS,

```
.tabs {
   width:100%;
}
.tab {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
```

The problem is that you are using **#tab** instead of **.tab**. Here id is not used. # is for id